# Creating a pie chart in swift

Tags: swift, initialization, pie-chart, init

I'm trying to create a pie chart in swift, and would like to create the code from scratch rather than use a 3rd party extension.

I like the idea of it being @IBDesignable, so I started with this:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class PieChart: UIView {

  var data:  Dictionary<String,Int>?

  required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder:aDecoder)!
    self.contentMode = .Redraw
  }

  override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    self.contentMode = .Redraw
  }

  override fun drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    // draw the chart in here
  }

}
```

What I'm not sure about, is how best to get the data into the chart. Should I have something like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var pieChart: PieChart!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    pieChart.data = pieData
    pieChart.setNeedsDisplay()
}
```

Or is there a better way? Presumably, there is no way to include the data in the init function?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: BTW, I'm inferring from the lack of any access control attributes that you've defined the `PieChart` within the same target as the view controller. It's generally advisable to set up a separate framework target for `@IBDesignable` views.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a convenience init that includes the data, but that would only be useful if you are creating the view from code.  If your view is added in the Storyboard, you will want a way to set the data after the view has been created.

It is good to look at the standard UI elements (like `UIButton`) for design clues.  You can change properties on a `UIButton` and it updates without you having to call `myButton.setNeedsDisplay()`, so you should design your pie chart to work in the same manner.

It is fine to have a property of your view that holds the data.  The view should take responsibility for redrawing itself, so define `didSet` for your `data` property and call `setNeedsDisplay()` there.

```
var data:  Dictionary<String,Int>? {
    didSet {
        // Data changed.  Redraw the view.
        self.setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}
```

Then you can simply set the data, and the pie chart will redraw:

```
pieChart.data = pieData
```

You can extend this to other properties on your pie chart.  For instance, you might want to change the background color.  You'd define `didSet` for that property as well and call `setNeedsDisplay`.

Note that `setNeedsDisplay` just sets a flag and the view will be drawn later.  Multiple calls to `setNeedsDisplay` won't cause your view to redraw multiple times, so you can do something like:

```
pieChart.data = pieData
pieChart.backgroundColor = .redColor()
pieChart.draw3D = true  // draw the pie chart in 3D
```

and the pieChart would redraw just once.

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot set the data in the `init` method if you have added this to a scene in a storyboard (because `init(coder:)` will be called).

So, yes, you could just populate the data for the pie chart in `viewDidLoad`.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    pieChart.dataPoints = ...
}
```

But, because this `PieChart` is `IBDesignable`, that means that you probably wanted to see a rendition of the pie chart in IB. So you can implement `prepareForInterfaceBuilder` in the `PieChart` class, supplying some sample data:

```
override public func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
    super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
    dataPoints = ...
}
```

That way you can now enjoy the designable view (e.g., see a preview; other inspectable properties can be manifested) in Interface Builder. The preview is our sample data, not the data that will be shown at runtime, but it may be enough to appreciate the overall design:

[image]

And, as vacawama said, you'd want to move the `setNeedsDisplay` into the `didSet` observer for the property.

```
public class PieChart: UIView {

    public var dataPoints: [DataPoint]? {          // use whatever type that makes sense for your app, though I'd suggest an array (which is ordered) rather than a dictionary (which isn't)
        didSet { setNeedsDisplay() }
    }

    @IBInspectable public var lineWidth: CGFloat = 2 {
        didSet { setNeedsDisplay() }
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: A fantastic answer Rob, and thank you to @vacawama for his ideas too, I've learned a huge amount from both answers. Rob, you say that it's advisable to set up a separate target for IBDesignable views - is that just for easier code re-use, or is there a more important reason?

Comment: @Ben - In WWDC 2014 video [What's New in Interface Builder](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014-411/), Apple simply says that designable views "need to be" in a separate target, but don't clearly articulate the rationale. I can imagine practical reasons (e.g. it actually builds and executes the target, so if you're in the middle of writing code in the main target, it might not be "buildable" when you go to IB; it will build that target more quickly or less frequently; etc.). I've seen it work, though, in the same target, but I've also seen people have problems when they did that.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case anybody looks at this question again, I wanted to post my finished code so that it can be useful to others. Here it is:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class PieChart: UIView {
    var dataPoints: Dictionary<String,Double> = ["Alpha":1,"Beta":2,"Charlie":3,"Delta":4,"Echo":2.5,"Foxtrot":1.4] {
        didSet { setNeedsDisplay() }
    }
    @IBInspectable var lineWidth: CGFloat = 1.0 {
        didSet { setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable var lineColor: UIColor = uicolor_normal {
        didSet { setNeedsDisplay() }
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder:aDecoder)!
        self.contentMode = .Redraw
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        self.contentMode = .Redraw
    }

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {


        // set font for labels
        let fieldColor: UIColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
        let fieldFont = uifont_piechartkey
        var fieldAttributes: NSDictionary = [
            NSForegroundColorAttributeName: fieldColor,
            NSFontAttributeName: fieldFont!
        ]

        // get the graphics context and prepare an inset box for the pie
        let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        let margin: CGFloat = lineWidth
        let box0 = CGRectInset(self.bounds, margin, margin)
        let keyHeight = CGFloat( ceil( Double(dataPoints.count) / 3.0) * 24 ) + 16
        let side : CGFloat = min(box0.width, box0.height-keyHeight)
        let box = CGRectMake((self.bounds.width-side)/2, (self.bounds.height-side-keyHeight)/2,side,side)
        let radius : CGFloat = min(box.width, box.height)/2.0


        // converts percentages to radians for drawing the segment
        func percent_to_rad(p: Double) -> CGFloat {
            let rad = CGFloat(p * 0.02 * M_PI)
            return rad
        }

        // draws a segment
        func draw_arc(start: CGFloat, end: CGFloat, color: CGColor) {
            CGContextBeginPath(ctx)
            CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, box.midX, box.midY)
            CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, color)
            CGContextAddArc(ctx,box.midX,box.midY,radius-lineWidth/2,start,end,0)
            CGContextClosePath(ctx)
            CGContextFillPath(ctx)
        }
        // draws a key item
        func draw_key(keyName: String, keyValue: Double, color: CGColor, keyX: CGFloat, keyY: CGFloat) {
            CGContextBeginPath(ctx)
            CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, keyX, keyY)
            CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, color)
            CGContextAddArc(ctx,keyX,keyY,8,0,CGFloat(2 * M_PI),0)
            CGContextClosePath(ctx)
            CGContextFillPath(ctx)
            keyName.drawInRect(CGRectMake(keyX + 12,keyY-8,self.bounds.width/3,16),withAttributes: fieldAttributes as? [String : AnyObject])
        }


        let total =  Double(dataPoints.values.reduce(0, combine: +)) // the total of all values
        // convert dictionary to sorted touples
        let dataPointsArray = dictionary_to_sorted_array(dataPoints)

        // now sort the dictionary into an Array
        var start = -CGFloat(M_PI_2) // start at 0 degrees, not 90
        var end: CGFloat
        var i = 0

        // draw all segments
        for dataPoint in dataPointsArray {
            end = percent_to_rad(Double( (dataPoint.value)/total) * 100 )+start
            draw_arc(start,end:end,color: uicolors_chart[i%uicolors_chart.count].CGColor)
            start = end
            i++
        }
        // the key
        var keyX = self.bounds.minX + 8
        var keyY = self.bounds.height - keyHeight + 32
            i = 0
        for dataPoint in dataPointsArray {
            draw_key(dataPoint.key, keyValue: dataPoint.value, color: uicolors_chart[i%uicolors_chart.count].CGColor, keyX: keyX, keyY: keyY)
            if((i+1)%3 == 0) {
                keyX = self.bounds.minX + 8
                keyY += 24
            } else {
                keyX += self.bounds.width / 3
            }
            i++
        }



    }
}
```

This will create a pie chart, that looks something like this:

[[image: The finished chart[1]]

The other bits of code you'll need are the colours array:

```
let uicolor_chart_1 = UIColor.init(red: 0.0/255, green:153.0/255, blue:255.0/255, alpha:1.0)  //16b
let uicolor_chart_2 = UIColor.init(red: 0.0/255, green:200.0/255, blue:120.0/255, alpha:1.0)
let uicolor_chart_3 = UIColor.init(red: 140.0/255, green:220.0/255, blue:0.0/255, alpha:1.0)
let uicolor_chart_4 = UIColor.init(red: 255.0/255, green:240.0/255, blue:0.0/255, alpha:1.0)
let uicolor_chart_5 = UIColor.init(red: 255.0/255, green:180.0/255, blue:60.0/255, alpha:1.0)
let uicolor_chart_6 = UIColor.init(red: 235.0/255, green:60.0/255, blue:150.0/255, alpha:1.0)
let uicolors_chart : [UIColor] = [uicolor_chart_1,uicolor_chart_2,uicolor_chart_3,uicolor_chart_4,uicolor_chart_5,uicolor_chart_6]
```

And the code to convert the dictionary to an array:

```
func dictionary_to_sorted_array(dict:Dictionary<String,Double>) ->Array<(key:String,value:Double)> {
    var tuples: Array<(key:String,value:Double)> = Array()
    let sortedKeys = (dict as NSDictionary).keysSortedByValueUsingSelector("compare:")
    for key in sortedKeys {
        tuples.append((key:key as! String,value:dict[key as! String]!))
    }
    return tuples
}
```