# how to create the pie Chart and fill percentage in swift

Tags: ios, swift2

I have create `UIView` from `UIViewController`, how to create pie chart in `UIView`?, I have create the `PieView` class for `UIView` and the class code is below,

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class pieView: UIView {

    public var dataPoints: [DataPoint]? {          // use whatever type that makes sense for your app, though I'd suggest an array (which is ordered) rather than a dictionary (which isn't)
        didSet { setNeedsDisplay() }
    }

    @IBInspectable internal var lineWidth: CGFloat = 2 {
        didSet { setNeedsDisplay() }
    }

}
```

I have confused what is format to be used? coreplot or charts `frameworks` or other any method.

`Objective-C` is get the custom code but i need `swift` language code, how to implement pie chart in `UIView` and fill percentage,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use [iOS-Charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts), very easy to create data source, tons of customization, u create dataname xVals from 1 array, and its value in yVals with another array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that code snippet was taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/33947052/1271826 where I imagined a simple `PieView` class defined something like:

```
import UIKit

public class DataPoint {
    let text: String
    let value: Float
    let color: UIColor

    public init(text: String, value: Float, color: UIColor) {
        self.text = text
        self.value = value
        self.color = color
    }
}

@IBDesignable public class PieView: UIView {

    public var dataPoints: [DataPoint]? {          // use whatever type that makes sense for your app, though I'd suggest an array (which is ordered) rather than a dictionary (which isn't)
        didSet { setNeedsDisplay() }
    }

    @IBInspectable public var lineWidth: CGFloat = 2 {
        didSet { setNeedsDisplay() }
    }

    override public func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
        dataPoints = [
            DataPoint(text: "foo", value: 3, color: UIColor.redColor()),
            DataPoint(text: "bar", value: 4, color: UIColor.yellowColor()),
            DataPoint(text: "baz", value: 5, color: UIColor.blueColor())
        ]
    }

    public override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        guard dataPoints != nil else {
            return
        }

        let center = CGPoint(x: bounds.size.width / 2.0, y: bounds.size.height / 2.0)
        let radius = min(bounds.size.width, bounds.size.height) / 2.0 - lineWidth
        let total = dataPoints?.reduce(Float(0)) { $0 + $1.value }
        var startAngle = CGFloat(-M_PI_2)

        UIColor.blackColor().setStroke()

        for dataPoint in dataPoints! {
            let endAngle = startAngle + CGFloat(2.0 * M_PI) * CGFloat(dataPoint.value / total!)

            let path = UIBezierPath()
            path.moveToPoint(center)
            path.addArcWithCenter(center, radius: radius, startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: endAngle, clockwise: true)
            path.closePath()
            path.lineWidth = lineWidth
            dataPoint.color.setFill()

            path.fill()
            path.stroke()

            startAngle = endAngle
        }
    }

    public override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}
```

And, if you added a `UIView` in IB and changed the base class to `PieView` and add an `@IBOutlet`, you could then do something like:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var pieView: PieView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        pieView.dataPoints = [
            DataPoint(text: "foo", value: 3, color: UIColor.redColor()),
            DataPoint(text: "bar", value: 4, color: UIColor.yellowColor()),
            DataPoint(text: "baz", value: 5, color: UIColor.blueColor())
        ]
    }

}
```

That yields:

[image]

Note, that's `@IBDesignable` (and implements `prepareForInterfaceBuilder`) so that when you add it to a storyboard, you'll see a sample pie chart.

Clearly, this is an absurdly simplistic implementation, but you can expand upon this as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no native support  for charts in swift or in apple`s framework. But there are plenty of projects on GitHub you can use. Try to use advanced search something like [chart language:swift](http://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=chart%20language%3Aswift)